# Why is this integral positive?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The assignment is to find the integral between the two curves:
$y = 2x-x^2$ and $y = 3-2x$.

When finding integral by hand I get a negative answer. But doing `Integral(f, g, 1, 3)` in GeoGebra gives me a positive answer. The book also says it's positive.

[image: problem]

Is it because the integral between two curves always is an area? And area is always positive?

Comment: We can't tell where your argument fails until you [edit] the question to show us that argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, usually area is positive.  The question should have read "Find the area between the two curves."

After all:  $$ A = \int_a^b (f(x) - g(x))  dx \approx 1.33$$ and

$$ - A  = \int_a^b (g(x) - f(x) ) dx \approx -1.33$$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the points of intersection of the two curves.)

Answer (score 1):

Integral and area are two different things.
An integral can be negative or zero. An area can not be negative.

Your mistake might be, that you take a different subtraction of the two functions.

It is $\int_1^3 f-g\neq\int_1^3 g-f$. This is where the different sign might come from.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake